# MongoDB "Connect failed. Operation now in progress"

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

yesterday appeared a strange behaviour:

on small load all queries take long time and then site return error 
"Connection to MongoDB failed. Operation now in progress" 
At mongostat we see about 10-30 connections (very small, because we 
usualy work with 400-500) 
But when I type "netstat -na | grep 27017" I see very big number of 
TCP connections (> 150):

http://pastebin.com/3ghtwkVd

Why mongodb closes connection but TCP still open?

We doesn't use persistent connections and always doing Mongo:close() 
at the end of scripts.

Site work on cloud system like Amazon EC2 (we doesn't observe any 
network issues)

10.1.1.16 - MongoDB 
10.1.1.7 - Apache 
1Gbit/s between servers 
OS: Debian 6 Squeeze 
MongoDB: 1.8.2 (with 1.6.6 we have the same problem) 
Apache 2 
PHP 5.3.6 
PHP mongo driver 1.1.0 (connection pooling in 1.2.x is very bad for 
us)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your driver (e.g. PHP) does not actually close the TCP connection even when you close it using the method.

If you're using PHP as a module, try graceful apache reload to make PHP module unloaded and loaded again. This way, destructors are called and connections are closed.

If you use PHP as fastcgi app, restart (kill/exec) it and invoke again.

File a bug if necessary.